# how to convert all activiti deployed bpmn files to camunda?

Tags: camunda

in camunda and activiti deployed files stored in "ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY" table and bpmn file inserted on blob column "bytes_".

i want convert all activiti deployed bpmn file to camunda.
what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Bernd wrote a blogpost about `How to migrate from Activiti to Camunda`.
The following description about the database migration is taken from the [blogpost](https://blog.camunda.org/post/2016/10/migrate-from-activiti-to-camunda/). The description is only an example for PostgreSQL, but this should also work for other databases (you can find the migration scripts for other databases [here](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-consulting/blob/master/snippets/activiti-migration/scripts/).

For more information's please read the [blogpost](https://blog.camunda.org/post/2016/10/migrate-from-activiti-to-camunda/).

> ## Database migration
>
> Camunda forked from Activiti 5.11.
>
> ### Migration for Activiti <= 5.11
>
> If you have Activiti < 5.11, upgrade to 5.11 first (by upgrade scripts provided by Activiti). Then run the upgrade script from Camunda 6.2 (the Camunda version based on Activiti) to 7.0 (the first forked Camunda version), see [postgres_engine_6.2_to_7.0.sql](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/master/distro/sql-script/upgrade/postgres_engine_6.2_to_7.0.sql) for Postgres, scripts for other databases are provided in the same folder.
>
> ### Migration for Activiti > 5.11
>
> For migrating newer versions we always check database differences manually for the specific Activiti version at hand.
>
> For Activiti 5.21 - the current version when the Activiti core team left - we did this procedure for you. If you have an Activiti version > 5.11 && < 5.21, then migrate to 5.21 by the Activiti upgrade mechanism. Afterwards, follow the instructions here.
>
> Basically you have to apply all provided [Camunda upgrade scripts](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/master/distro/sql-script/upgrade/) from version 6.2 (the last Camunda version before the fork) to 7.5. However, you have to take care of some conflicts with changes in Activiti (you can see the changes in the beginning of [this commit](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-consulting/commit/f31ecc94bc825c5702376887b10da4d6b0cf6381) if you are interested in the details).
>
> To make it easy for you, we prepared special upgrade files you can apply without modifications. Make sure you run them in this order (e.g., by command line using `psql -U postgres -d activiti < postgres-1-upgrade.sql`):
>
> - [postgres-1-upgrade.sql](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-consulting/blob/master/snippets/activiti-migration/scripts/postgres-1-upgrade.sql): Upgrade the database to 7.5. No need to review this file.
> - [postgres-2-migrate.sql](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-consulting/blob/master/snippets/activiti-migration/scripts/postgres-2-migrate.sql): Migrates some tables/columns to be compliant with Camunda database. You might want to have a look to make sure you are fine with the changes.
> - [postgres-3-drop.sql](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-consulting/blob/master/snippets/activiti-migration/scripts/postgres-3-drop.sql): Drops unused tables and columns from the database. You should double-check that you do not lose data you rely on.
>
> Note that there are corresponding files for your database [in this github folder](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-consulting/blob/master/snippets/activiti-migration/scripts/).
>
> After this procedure, your database is a Camunda BPM 7.5 database. Congrats! You can now run Camunda and your runtime data is still there.
>
> **Warning:** This migration script is provided without any warranty. We haven't tested it for all circumstances and you might lose data, especially if you used features not supported by Camunda. Make a backup before applying the migration and verify everything is working afterwards! Let us know if you experience errors.

Comment: thanks for replying, i migrate successfully but i want to  convert all previuse deployed bpm file to camunda. in realy i want to  convert all data  that stored in column **bytes_** on table **ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY**. in my application differnt verson of any process exist.

Comment: Why don't you do a redeploy of the processes to the new db?

Comment: @Jan I thought the same :)

Comment: @Jan Galinski  I do that and all of my  new process redeployed to new db but because some of those Have changed over time   and a lot of instance of those executed and finished when I search  in my app on archive (contain all task done) camunda engine parser throws parsing exception (activiti:formKey vs camunda:formKey).

Comment: You have to redeploy a new fixed version of theses processes. Which mean you need to adjust theses process definitions and fix all errors.

Comment: @Jan Galinski ,@ Zelldon its very hard because i don't have previous version of my process. those only are in db. I think in one way, I have to update the existing data on column byte_ and replace all "activiti:" word with "camunda:" .