# How to perform a correct Activiti to Camunda migration

Tags: migration, activiti, camunda

I’m a little bit confused how to migrate from Activiti to Camunda. Our current database is on Activiti version 5.14. I wrote a rollbackscript to 5.11 to be able to update from Activiti 5.11 straight to camunda 7.0.0 as described in official Activiti migration guide (https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/update/activiti/).

It says Camunda 7.0.0 is basically Activiti 5.11 and the database should be identicial. However in this Camunda blog (https://camunda.com/blog/2016/10/migrate-from-activiti-to-camunda/) I have to execute additional scripts (6.2 to 7.0) and on github (https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/tree/7.0.0-Final/distro/sql-script/upgrade) are some other scripts as well (6.0->6.1, 6.1->6.2, 6.2->7.0).

[how to convert all activiti deployed bpmn files to camunda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48077182/how-to-convert-all-activiti-deployed-bpmn-files-to-camunda) mentioned the 6.2 -> 7.0 script as well.

Can someone tell me which scripts I have to execute and why?

Thanks!

My same question in the official forum: https://forum.camunda.org/t/required-sql-scripts-for-activiti-to-camunda-migration/25794

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you consider Activiti to Flowable. It's a much easier transition and Flowable is fully supported by the original Activiti team.
P.S> I don't work for Flowable so don't have a dog in the fight.

Comment: Camunda is widely used in our company with good experiences so we want to comply with the company standard. But thanks for the suggestion!